# Calling a method that takes a variable parameter list with an array

Tags: c#, parameter-passing, variadic-functions

Consider this method:

```cs
public static void InvokeAsync(params object[] arguments)
{
    // do something
}
```

Now I want to call it with a single argument of type `string[]`:

```cs
InvokeAsync(new string[] { "Test" });
```

unfortunately, that results in `arguments` becoming the `string[]` instance and `arguments[1] == "Test"`. I need the string array to be the first element of the object[] array.

I can work around this by using:

```cs
InvokeAsync(new object[] { new string[] { "Test" }});
```

but this defeats a bit the purpose of a `params` declaration and is also not nice (and not obvious!). Is there a better way?

Comment: "Now I want to call it with a single argument of type string[]". So why are you using the `params` declaration  in the first place?

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you need to declare it as taking an `object[]` instead of specific type of array or making the class generic?

Comment: @Powerlord The actual method is from a class that performs generic calls via reflection.

Comment: @ShawnOrr This is where the problem happens. For other actual parameter types, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the correct way. Arrays are [covariant in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) so implicit conversion from `string[]` to `object[]` exists (which is actually not type safe, see the linked doc) and is used by compiler to treat your `new string[] { "Test" }` as `arguments` array. So you need to "explain" to the compiler what you actually want with this workaround.

If you will actually have multiple parameters everything will work as expected:

```
InvokeAsync(new string[] { "Test" }, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

try  this method

```
public static object InvokeAsync(params object[] arguments)
{
  if (!arguments.GetType().Name.Contains("Object")) arguments = 
                                                     new object[] { arguments };
  return arguments;
}
```

test

```
var result1 =InvokeAsync(new string[] { "Test1","Test2"});
var result2 =InvokeAsync(new string[] { "Test1","Test2"},new string[] { "Test3","Test4"} );
var result3 =InvokeAsync(new string[] { "Test1","Test2"}, 3 );
```

result1

```
[
  [
    "Test1",
    "Test2"
  ]
]
```

result2

```
[
  [
    "Test1",
    "Test2"
  ],
  [
    "Test3",
    "Test4"
  ]
]
```

result 3

```
[
  [
    "Test1",
    "Test2"
  ],
  1
]
```